# Server Gets Restarted while installing Ubuntu

Tags: package-management

I'm using Fujitsu Primergy Rx200 S8 server, when I installing Ubuntu 13.10 server edition the server gets restarted itself at the time of "Installing the system" after partitioning step. The media installing pre required file at this stage, on the completion of 83% the package "preparing linux-image-extra-3.11.0-12-generic" try to install but its failed and the server gets restarted. What is the issue?